# extending jQuery-UI's icons

Tags: css, jquery-ui

On one project of mine I need to extend the icon palette of jQuery-UI's icons. I needed slightly bigger (22x22) and colorful ones.

So I took a look at how jQuery-UI creates the icons and did the same with my icons. I wanted my "extension" as jQuery-UI-ish as possible so I began overwriting some css classes as well. My idea is

```
<div class="ui-rw-icon">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil"></span>
</div>
```

to use a `ui-rw-icon` (or `ui-rw-icon-color` for colorful icons) class that wraps jQuery-UI's icon classes with which I can control the css behavior. My css file has the following content:

```
.ui-rw-icon .ui-icon {
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    background-image: url(images/ui-rw-icons_grayscale_246x246.png);
}
.ui-state-default .ui-rw-icon .ui-icon { background-image: url(images/ui-rw-icons_grayscale_pale_246x246.png); }
.ui-state-hover .ui-rw-icon .ui-icon { background-image: url(images/ui-rw-icons_grayscale_246x246.png); }

.ui-rw-icon-color .ui-icon { width: 22px; height: 22px; background-image: url(images/ui-rw-icons_color_246x246.png); }
.ui-state-default .ui-rw-icon-color .ui-icon { background-image: url(images/ui-rw-icons_color_pale_246x246.png); }
.ui-state-hover .ui-rw-icon-color .ui-icon { background-image: url(images/ui-rw-icons_color_246x246.png); }


/* positioning */
.ui-rw-icon-color .ui-icon-pencil, .ui-rw-icon .ui-icon-pencil { background-position: 0 0; }
.ui-rw-icon-color .ui-icon-remove, .ui-rw-icon .ui-icon-remove { background-position: -32px 0; }
```

This works fine, my icons get displayed. The only problem is that the icons are 6 pixels bigger than those of jQuery-UI and sometimes I would want to reposition them so that they fit better. For example here

```
<button name="pencil" class="menubar-button ui-rw-icon" id="menubar-meassure">Measures</button>
<button name="script" class="menubar-button" id="menubar-newmeasure">New Measure</button>

<script>
$('.menubar-button').each(function() {
        $(this).button({
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-" + $(this).attr("name")
            }
        })
    });

</script>
```

This is how it looks:

[image]
<sub>(source: [sakuranohana.org](http://sakuranohana.org/buttons.png))</sub>

I'd like the pencil to be some pixels higher. I found the rule on jquery-ui-css file that controls the position inside a button:

```
.ui-button-icon-only .ui-icon,
.ui-button-text-icon-primary .ui-icon,
.ui-button-text-icon-secondary .ui-icon,
.ui-button-text-icons .ui-icon,
.ui-button-icons-only .ui-icon { 
     position: absolute; 
     top: 50%; 
     margin-top: -8px;
}
```

So I thought I could do the same here as I did with the `background-image` attribute:

```
.ui-rw-icon .ui-button-icon-only .ui-icon,
.ui-rw-icon .ui-button-text-icon-primary .ui-icon,
.ui-rw-icon .ui-button-text-icon-secondary .ui-icon,
.ui-rw-icon .ui-button-text-icons .ui-icon,
.ui-rw-icon .ui-button-icons-only .ui-icon {
     top: 40%;
}
```

but this doesn't work. Opera dragonfly and Firebug both show me that the positioning rule comes from `jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.css` and not from my `rw-ui.css`. The `button()` function created this code:

```
<button name="pencil" class="menubar-button ui-rw-icon ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-primary ui-state-focus" id="menubar-" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
  <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-pencil"></span>
  <span class="ui-button-text">Measures</span>
</button>
```

I cannot understand why my css class is ignored. I tried using css selectors but they didn't help either. I had a similar problem when trying to extend the behavior of when the object has the `ui-state-hover`, I just couldn't overwrite jQuery-UI's css rules.

What am I missing here?

---

**EDIT**

well, after reading the [Class Selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html) section I realized that my problem is that the class `ui-button-text-icon-primary` is in the same set of classes as `ui-rw-icon` hence the selector `.ui-rw-icon .ui-button-text-icon-primary .ui-icon` doesn't work. But this helped:

```
.ui-rw-icon.ui-button-icon-only .ui-icon,
.ui-rw-icon.ui-button-text-icon-primary .ui-icon,
.ui-rw-icon.ui-button-text-icon-secondary .ui-icon,
.ui-rw-icon.ui-button-text-icons .ui-icon,
.ui-rw-icon.ui-button-icons-only .ui-icon {
     top: 40%;
}
```

a small change but an important one.

Answer (score 0):

- For you custom icons to take effect, your css file should be called
  AFTER the jquery ui css.
- If your style is still not getting applied, try to go one level up while defining the CSS path, i.e. if your HTML is:

  ```
  <div id="menubar">
      <button id="measures">Measures</button>
  </div>
  ```

then your styles should be:

```
    #menubar .ui-rw-icon.ui-button-icon-only .ui-icon,
    #menubar .ui-rw-icon.ui-button-text-icon-primary .ui-icon,
    #menubar .ui-rw-icon.ui-button-text-icon-secondary .ui-icon,
    #menubar .ui-rw-icon.ui-button-text-icons .ui-icon,
    #menubar .ui-rw-icon.ui-button-icons-only .ui-icon {
         top: 40%;
    }
```